# Cannot satisfy `'static` lifetime requirement

Tags: rust, yew

I am trying to create an app with `yew`. I have a list of players and i want to toggle their state from active to inactive but i struggle with object lifetime. `rustc` tells me that the `self` in my `view` function needs `'static` lifetime requirement but i don't know how to achieve this. How can i satisfy this lifetime requirement?

`` error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement ``

```rust
pub struct App {
    state: State,
}

pub struct State {
    pub players: Vec<Player>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    pub name: String,
    pub score: usize,
    pub is_active: bool,
}

impl Component for App {
//... Omitted some boilerplate code for create and update
    fn view(&self, ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        // This gives us a component's "`Scope`" which allows us to send messages, etc to the component.
        let link = ctx.link();
        html! {
            <div>
                <button onclick={link.callback(|_| Msg::AddOne)}>{ "+1" }</button>

                <div id="players">
                {
                    self.state.players.iter().map(|p| {
                        
                        html!{
                        <div  key={p.name.as_str()}>
                        <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        class="toggle"
                        checked={p.is_active}
                        onclick={link.callback(move |_| Msg::Toggle(p.name))}
                    />
                        { format!("Hello, I'am {}!",p.name) }</div>
                    
                    }
                    }).collect::<Html>()
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Full diagnostic message:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> src/main.rs:69:40
    |
60  |     fn view(&self, ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
    |             ----- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
...
69  |                     self.state.players.iter().map(|p| {
    |                     ------------------ ^^^^
    |                     |
    |                     ...is used here...
...
77  |                         onclick={link.callback(move |_| Msg::Toggle(p.name))}
    |                                       -------- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
    |
note: `'static` lifetime requirement introduced by this bound
   --> /Users/benny.gaechter/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/yew-0.20.0/src/html/component/scope.rs:144:26
    |
144 |         F: Fn(IN) -> M + 'static,
    |                          ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the error message: The argument given to `.callback()` needs to be some `Fn(IN) -> M + 'static`, that is, a function that takes some `IN` as an argument, returns some `M` as a result, and as a whole is `'static` (has no lifetimes shorter than `'static`).

A plain function pointer is `'static`, and so are closures that capture context no shorter than `'static`. But the closure `move |_| Msg::Toggle(p.name)` captures `p.name`, where `p` comes from `self.state.players`, and `self` in `self.state.players` comes from `fn view(&self, ...)`. The argument `&self` to `view()` is not `'static`, and this is what the compiler complains about: The only way to make the closure passed to `callback()` `'static` is for `view()` to be `fn view(&'static self, ...)`.

An `fn view(&'static self, ...)` is probably not what you want to do or can do, but the compiler doesn't know that.

What you need to do is make the closure `move |_| Msg::Toggle(p.name)` `'static` by disentangling it from the locally bound `p`. It may be enough to `.clone()` `p.name` and `move` the clone into the closure. As the clone is an owned `String` which has no lifetimes shorter than `'static`, the closure itself becomes `'static`, satisfying the requirement of `.callback()`. This, however, would mean that `Player::name` *could* change independently of what the callback has. If that is a possibility in your code, use a `Rc`/`Arc` and `.clone()` that; same argument: As the `Rc`/`Arc` owned by the closure is `'static`, the closure itself becomes `'static`.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation `.clone()` did help here and i do not need to worry about `Player::name` changing in the meantime as the whole system is sufficiently simple (i.e. Player cannot change their names...).